# How to call the command line in vb6

Tags: vb6

I want to call the below command line in VB6. How can i call this:

```
hh.exe "ms-its:c:/Program Files (x86)/GST/Timken Syber Program/TimkenAnalysisHelp.chm::/01_Quick_Start_Guide/quickstart_initial_program_setup.htm"
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the command line you use *Shell*:

```
Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

If there are quotation marks, encode these by providing them twice:

```
Shell "notepad.exe ""Test.txt""", vbNormalFocus
```

I can't test your command line, as it features things and locations I don't have, but presumably the following should work:

```
Shell "hh.exe ""ms-its:c:/Program Files (x86)/GST/Timken Syber Program" & _
"/TimkenAnalysisHelp.chm::/01_Quick_Start_Guide/quickstart_initial_program_setup.htm""", _
vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine for me.

Comment: Mark it as the answer @Mahantesh